# MOXy JAXB unable to unmarshall into List<int[]>

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I was able to unmarshall the structure below to List using Oracle JDK 1.8 standard library.

```
<parent>
    <child>1234 1234 1234</child>
    <child>1231 1313 1331</child>
</parent>
```

where I have a and XmlAdapter class like below to tokenize String to int[] vice versa  and using XMlJavaTypeAdapter on the root XML class like below.

```
class ChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,int[]> {
    ...
}


@XmlRootElement(name="parent")
class Parent {
    ...
    private List<int[]> children;
    ...
    @XmlElement(name="child")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ChildAdapter.class)
    public void setChildren(List<int[]> children) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

but I got an Exception when I switch to use EclipseLink MOXy implementation.
Has anyone tried this before?

```
Exception [EclipseLink-33] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Trying to invoke [setChildren] on the object with the value [[I@1f9f6368].  The number of actual and formal parameters differs, or an unwrapping conversion has failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[childrenList-->child/text()]
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(mypackage.Parent --> [DatabaseTable(Parent)])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.illegalArgumentWhileSettingValueThruMethodAccessor(DescriptorException.java:714)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:286)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:239)
```

...

Using Moxy, the only way is I need to create a Wrapper class to holds the int[] like below, but it is not what I really want.

```
class ChildWrapper {
    private int[] childs;
    public void setChilds(int[] childs) {
        this.childs = childs
    }
    public int[] getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }
}
```

Changed the adapter to `class ChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, ChildWrapper>`.

Suprizingly the `List<int[]> children` has now become `List<ChildWrapper> children` in the resulting object. I didn't change parent, so the unmarshaller now create a different object through reflection or something? Isn't this broken?

Comment: What do you mean broken? Do you get different results? Getting errors? What?

Comment: I got an exception, hold on i try to regenerate it.

Comment: Debugging it, it seems the unmarshaller tried to assign the result of int[] directly to children. Accidentally I found a way to make it work but it does not seems right to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround.
Seems like the problem here Moxy do not like List of List `List<List<T>>`.

I created an XML Adapter of type `<String,Object>` and casted the object to List and use this for `@XMLJavaTypeAdapter(ChildAdapter.class)` annotation.

```
public class ChildAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object unmarshall(String v) {
         List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
         ...Tokenize your String v and add them to result...
         return result;
    }


    @Override
    public String marshall(Object v) {
         List<Integer> l = (List<Integer)v;
         StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
         ...Loop l and append b...
         return b.toString();
    }
}
```